# How to use data table to create a new table which shows proportion of rows which meet condition?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use data table to see per column, how many rows meet a condition (as a proportion of total number of rows) and to have this in an output table, so there is 1 obs per column with this value. For example, as input

```
 structure(list(A = c(57L, 546L, 3245L, 34L, 356L), B = c(24L, 
 65L, 5678L, 453L, 32L), C = c(567L, 4328L, 56789L, 2345L, 654L
  ), D = c(987L, 456L, 786L, 23975L, 21L), E = c(345L, 678L, 3456L, 
   89L, 234L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I've been trying to use the below without much success:

```
   df1 <- as.data.table(df)

   out <- df1[, sapply(.SD, function(x) c(any(x <= 60)/.N))]
```

I would like the output to be something like this for each condition:

```
      <=60
          A    B    C    D    E
         0.4  0.4   0   0.2   0

     >60& <1000
         A     B     C     D     E
         0.4  0.4   0.2   0.6   0.8
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve your problem:

```
df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) c(sum(x<=60), sum(x>60 & x<1000))/.N)]

       A     B     C     D     E
1:   0.4   0.4   0.0   0.2   0.0
2:   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.6   0.8
```